# EditText глючит с адаптером

Tags: java, android

```
    public class AdapterList extends RecyclerView.Adapter<AdapterList.ParentViewHolder>{
    private String mDataSet[];
    private Context context;

    public AdapterList(Context context,String data[]) {
        mDataSet = data;
        this.context=context;
    }

    @Override
    public ParentViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return new ParentViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate( R.layout.adap,null ));
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final ParentViewHolder holder, final int position) {
//        holder.anameTxtView.setText(mDataSet.get(position).getDname());
//        holder.abalanceTxtView.setText(mDataSet.get(position).getDbalance());
        holder.editText.setText( mDataSet[position] );

        holder.editText.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View v, boolean hasFocus) {
                if (!hasFocus){
                    String str=holder.editText.getText().toString();
                    holder.editText.setText( str );
                    mDataSet[position]=str;
                }
            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataSet.length;
    }

    class ParentViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        private EditText editText;

        public ParentViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            editText= (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

> Думаю глядя на гифку все ясно станет в чем моя беда

Adapter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatEditText
            android:textColor="#000"
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: У нас тут штук десять вопросов с вашей проблемой. Поищите, вроде, вопросы про чек-боксы в ListView

Comment: Дак в ListvIew это работает. в Recycler View нет. Я что думаете не читаю свои темы))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Здесь проблема с размером самого `EditText` на разметке, указано значение `wrap_content`, при котором при вводе длинного текста виджет расширяется, затем при переиспользовании адаптером сохраняется его прошлый размер.

Вам нужно либо установить размер `EditText` `match_parent` с маржинами, либо в `onBindViewHolder()` каждый раз заново переназначать атрибут `wrap_content` при установке текста в виджет, чтобы он соответствовал текущему размеру текста, либо еще как-то решать проблему с динамическим размером виджета.

Comment: У меня и так match_parent стоит. Щяс попробую wrap

Comment: Wrap помог. Благодарствую дружище))